# How to replace all occurrences in a file with unique value for each occurrence

Tags: sed, replace

I am having one xml file which has multiple occurrences MyID as shown below.

`MyID="dett090900990000"`

I want to replace all occurrences of `MyID=""` value with unique value.

For e.g. if I have three occurrences of `MyID=""` in an xml file, when I will be running script, I will pass one argument that will be used as MyID value (but incremental value will be assigned to each occurrences).

i.e. when I will run my script as `myscript.sh 7777777878889888`

Output should be as below (that means all the value for MyID will be changed and now will have unique values). It can be anything (number, string, and mixed)..

`MyID="77777778788898881"`
`MyID="77777778788898882"`
`MyID="77777778788898883"`

As you can see, 1, 2 & 3 will be appended to the provided value.

I am looking simple command to solve this problem! Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, you've dropped the leading "dett" letters, replacing the entire value with an indexed alternative?

Comment: yeah, I don't care about original value, whatever I pass as an argument (in above case I passed `7777777878889888` and now that will be used to replace all the occurances of `MyID=""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl it can be done like this:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $v=shift; }
          s/(MyID=")[^"]*(")/$1.$v.++$t.$2/ge' 7777777878889888 foo.xml bar.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly simple, but it works. Script takes two arguments, Arg1 is the string to match, Arg2 is the filename of the input file. This solution uses awk instead of sed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh
# Usage myscript.sh <string to match> <filename>

MyID=$1

awk -v MyID=$MyID 'BEGIN{ mynum=1; } { if (match($0,MyID) ) { sub(MyID, sprintf("%s%d", MyID, mynum) ) mynum++; } print }' $2
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work. :( I guess it is because in my XML all MyID occurances are unique already!

Comment: I understood your question to mean that you were looking for a match that you then wanted to append a sequential delimiter.